# Data logging issue

Tags: javascript, html, arduino

I have a web server set up from my arduino and the web page is loaded from it. I use ajax to print the data in the web page.

Similarly I need to store the data in a local pc as a text file. I was successful initially in storing a text file, but the issue is that the data dosent get appended in the same file, there are multiple files created per instance.

Can someone help me in solving this issue. I'm restricted to use only javascript.

```js
client.println("document.getElementById(\"flux_values_1\").innerHTML = this.responseText;");
client.println("var textToSave =[this.responseText]");
client.println("var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:'text/plain'});");
client.println("var textToSaveAsURL = URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);");
client.println("var fileNameToSaveAs = \"as\";");
client.println("var downloadLink = document.createElement(\"a\");");
client.println("downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;");
client.println("downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;");
client.println("document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);");
client.println("downloadLink.click();");
```

Comment: The only practicable solution I see is to write the files with names that can be sorted in the right order (seq number or dates) and then concatenate the files on your PC  from time to time or when needed. You can also use Web Storage from modern browsers to build an internal cache and append new text to this. Thereafter overwrite the file with the cached Textdata. But there is a limit for Webstorage of about 32 kbytes (I do not remember the correct value).

Comment: The easiest way would be to let the arduino deliver only the data text. This is read by a script (python, javascript/nodejs, perl, bash or whatever you want) and then build a web server on your PC that delivers this data on a web page. Or simpler a script that create HTML pages from the data.  If that could be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are downloading the file in browser, you cannot append data in a file via browser, you have to do this in backend. Browser will always create a new file and download a new file. This is expected behaviour and cannot be changed.